# How can I get testing accuracy using tensorboard for Detectron2?

Tags: python, object-detection, tensorboard

I'm learning to use Detecron2. I've followed [this](https://www.dlology.com/blog/how-to-train-detectron2-with-custom-coco-datasets/) link to create a custom object detector. 
My training code -

```
# training Detectron2
from detectron2.engine import DefaultTrainer
from detectron2.config import get_cfg
import os

cfg = get_cfg()
cfg.merge_from_file("./detectron2_repo/configs/COCO-InstanceSegmentation/mask_rcnn_R_50_FPN_3x.yaml")
cfg.DATASETS.TRAIN = ("pedestrian",)
cfg.DATASETS.TEST = ()   # no metrics implemented for this dataset
cfg.DATALOADER.NUM_WORKERS = 2
cfg.MODEL.WEIGHTS = "detectron2://COCO-InstanceSegmentation/mask_rcnn_R_50_FPN_3x/137849600/model_final_f10217.pkl"  # initialize from model zoo
cfg.SOLVER.IMS_PER_BATCH = 2
cfg.SOLVER.BASE_LR = 0.02
cfg.SOLVER.MAX_ITER = 300    # 300 iterations seems good enough, but you can certainly train longer
cfg.MODEL.ROI_HEADS.BATCH_SIZE_PER_IMAGE = 128   # faster, and good enough for this dataset
cfg.MODEL.ROI_HEADS.NUM_CLASSES = 1  

os.makedirs(cfg.OUTPUT_DIR, exist_ok=True)
trainer = DefaultTrainer(cfg)
trainer.resume_or_load(resume=False)
trainer.train()
```

It saves a log file in output dir thus I can use tensorboard to show the training accuracy -

```
%load_ext tensorboard
%tensorboard --logdir output
```

It works fine and I can see my model's training accuracy. But When testing/validating the model -

```
cfg.MODEL.WEIGHTS = os.path.join(cfg.OUTPUT_DIR, "model_final.pth")
cfg.MODEL.ROI_HEADS.SCORE_THRESH_TEST = 0.7   # set the testing threshold for this model
cfg.DATASETS.TEST = ("pedestrian_day", )
predictor = DefaultPredictor(cfg)
```

Although from Detectron2 tutorial I've got -

```
from detectron2.evaluation import COCOEvaluator, inference_on_dataset
from detectron2.data import build_detection_test_loader
evaluator = COCOEvaluator("pedestrian_day", cfg, False, output_dir="./output/")
val_loader = build_detection_test_loader(cfg, "pedestrian_day", mapper=None)
inference_on_dataset(trainer.model, val_loader, evaluator)
```

but this gives the AP, AP50, AP75, APm, APl and APs for both training and testing. 
My question is how can I able to see the testing accuracy in tensorboard like the training one?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By default [evaluation during training is disabled](https://github.com/facebookresearch/detectron2/blob/0b500b4d7ed11e9728867298f5f168fb34908e2c/detectron2/config/defaults.py#L551-L553)

If you would like to enable it you have to set below param

```py
# set eval step intervals
cfg.TEST.EVAL_PERIOD =
```

But for evaluation to work you have to modify [build_evaluator](https://github.com/facebookresearch/detectron2/blob/0b500b4d7ed11e9728867298f5f168fb34908e2c/detectron2/engine/defaults.py#L466-L479) function in detectron2/engine/defaults.py

An example of [build_evaluator](https://github.com/facebookresearch/detectron2/blob/0b500b4d7ed11e9728867298f5f168fb34908e2c/tools/train_net.py#L52-L99) function is provided in tools/train_net.py script of https://github.com/facebookresearch/detectron2 repo

[This issue in detectron2](https://github.com/facebookresearch/detectron2/issues/810#issuecomment-602238878) discusses about creating custom LossEvalHook to monitor eval loss, sounds like a good approach to try